# nouislider: adding pips non-numerical last value?

Tags: nouislider

Is there a way to show a non-numerical last pips value. for instance, showing pips scale for 0, 100, 200, 300, More

Thanx for this great script!

Answer (score 4):

The following solution is a bit of a hack but it will do what you want.

You can use the `format` option and send it to a function which translates the values via a `switch` statement.

```javascript
function updatePips( value, type ){

    switch(true)   {
        case (value > 300):
            value = "More"
            break;       
    }
    return value;
}

$("#pips-steps").noUiSlider_pips({
    mode: 'steps',
    density: 100,
    format: {to: updatePips}
});
```